# Can reviewers review suggested edits more than 20 times?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

I thought you aren't able to perform more than 20 reviews of one sort per day.  But in https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/stats, it looks like Videonauth has reviewed 21.  Is that possible?

[image]

Comment: They can always review edits on their own posts.

Comment: Ah, is that what happened there!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The twenty-first review was indeed for [one of Videonauth's own posts](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/576607).